Facebook: getting page information in php api - permissions granted
Ok, we have an app, many of our customers are using it. The app requests access to the FB users' pages, in order to make posts to the page. Our app is using Facebook Login for Business, and so has to use a "Configuration" to request access. In that configuration, I am asking for:
email
public_profile
pages_show_list
pages_read_engagement
pages_manage_posts
business_management (added recently)

I need to get a list of the pages "under" the Facebook account that they are giving me access to. I am using the PHP API, and making the request:
https://graph.facebook.com/v20.0/me/accounts/?access_token=<access token>

Most of the time, I am getting the list of pages just fine. But for some accounts, I get no pages. An example page is https://www.facebook.com/thomas.mcgroder.  Now, when I click on the house icon to get to his Home page I see that there is a page under "Your Pages and profiles". Why can't I see it? Also, when I run through the Facebook Log In, I don't seem to get any questions related to the business_management permissions. I am at a loss here - from my reading, I don't get the list of pages because that permission is not in the access token, but I don't see how to get that permission inserted into the Log In process. This has been driving me crazy for weeks now.
One additional thing. My customer allowed me to log into his account for this testing. When I use my own personal account, during the Facebook Log In, on the page where I can review the access request, I see one extra section that starts with:
This integration enables <my app> to establish a connection with your business portfolio(s)

This does not always show up,and I don't understand why. I suspect that is the core problem.
